# How to change the column type from string to varchar using script/generate in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-generate

Trying to migrate a sqlite3 db for a rails app to mysql db.  The column named "content" was a string type in sqlite3. I want to change it to varchar (or perhaps text) in mysql.  I am not sure if there is a way to do this by using "ruby script/generate" command. Any ideas?  Obviously, I could start all over again with desired column types but wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: I would really encourage you to use the migrations directly, as they are database-agnostic. You can easily run them against any database engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you've defined your column type as a string in your schema, then it will already be a VARCHAR in mysql. If you want to change it to a text field, create a migration using something like `script/generate Migration ChangeModelxContentToText` and then use `change_column` to change it.